# A Button, using telebot library

Tags: python, bots, telegram

I have a `handler` for upload documents in telegram bot. I would like to get if user presses button `1` - the handler starts to work. But I can't undestand , what I should do with param `message`, I need another argument **not** `message` in `progress_step` for my handler of uploading docs and pictures in order to see my uploading file, but now I get for handler text:`1`.Plese< can you help?

My code:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda m: True, content_types=['document'])
def handle_docs_photo(message):
            try:
                chat_id = message.chat.id

                file_info = bot.get_file(message.document.file_id)
                downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)

                src = 'B:/' + message.document.file_name;
                with open(src, 'wb') as new_file:
                    new_file.write(downloaded_file)

                bot.reply_to(message, "save that")
            except Exception as e:
                bot.reply_to(message, e)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['help', 'start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True)
    markup.add('1', '2') #Имена кнопок
    msg = bot.reply_to(message, 'Test text', reply_markup=markup)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_step)

def process_step(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    if message.text=='1':
        #here should be  def handle_docs_photo(message):
    else:
        pass
```